# animating orientation changes

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a view added with

```
id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIWindow *window = [appDelegate window];
[window addSubview:self.view];
```

but while the view will rotate, it doesnt animate to the new orientation like the view behind it does. How could I get it to do so?

EDIT:
I based my code off Jeff MaMarche's tutorial:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t set the view controller as the root view controller of the window, you won’t get rotation notifications. You can sign up for those notifications like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             name:UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
                                         selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:)
                                           object:nil];
```

Then implement a method called `-orientationDidChange:`, and in that method (as well as when you add the view to the window directly) set the view’s `transform` property to rotate it appropriately.

Comment: my main view controller does receive rotation notifications, just not the controller in charge of this other view